# How to find mongodb data with not equal multiple ids?

Tags: php, nosql

I have a scenario like :

I have some ids in array like : [5adcbe766803fa6b048b4599, 5adcbe766803fa6b048b4567]

```
$ids = [5adcbe766803fa6b048b4599, 5adcbe766803fa6b048b4567] ;
```

when I try to find with :

```
db.users.find(array('_id': array('$nin' : '$ids')));
```

I get some results which are not correct.

but if I use other fields like:

```
db.users.find(array('name': array('$nin' : 'asghar')));
```

Now results are correct.

Comment: _"I get some results which are not correct."_ Could you show us some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass ids in this way.

```
db.users.find(array('_id': array('$nin' : '$ids')));
```

Here is solution:

```
$idsAll = array();
foreach ($ids as $k=>$v) {
                $idsAll[] =  new MongoId($v);
            }
db.users.find(array('_id': array('$nin' : $idsAll)));
```